# Can Powershell put counter values in the system tray?

Tags: windows, powershell, performancecounter, system-tray

I am trying to monitor my Wifi adapter's throughput numerically on the system tray; like so.
[image]

I figured out the static Powershell query

`((Get-Counter '\\mullick1\network interface(intel[r] centrino[r] advanced-n 6205)\bytes total/sec').countersamples).cookedvalue*8/102400000*100`

But how can I get the continuous feed and how do I put it on the system tray ?
I found an alternate solution in the [Diskled](http://helgeklein.com/blog/2009/11/how-to-easily-monitor-system-performance-with-the-new-diskled-1-1/) software. But it doesn't show the actual value.

Comment: You'll need to create a WinFroms GUI so you can make use of instances of [`NotifyIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx). Then use a timer to grab new values of the counter and update your icon.

Comment: @Richard I am not well versed with .Net programming. Do I need to code and compile something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/74/Adding-Icons-to-the-System-Tray) ?

Comment: Take a look at [this blog post](http://www.sapien.com/blog/2012/05/08/spotlight-on-the-notifyicon-control/).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Looks like this is it. But can't get the function to work. Error:  `Show-NotifyIcon : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'NotifyIcon'. The argument is null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the script to render(update) a text at a notify icon.

Customize the "Get-NotifyIconText" function as you like.

```
#Requires -Version 3.0

function Get-NotifyIconText {
  [DateTime]::Now.Second.ToString()
 # ((Get-Counter '\\mypc\network interface(Intel[R] 82579V Gigabit Network Connection)\bytes total/sec').countersamples).cookedvalue*8/102400000*100
}

Add-Type -ReferencedAssemblies @("System.Windows.Forms"; "System.Drawing") -TypeDefinition @"
    using System;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    public static class TextNotifyIcon
    {
        // it's difficult to call DestroyIcon() with powershell only...
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32")]
        private static extern bool DestroyIcon(IntPtr hIcon);

        public static NotifyIcon CreateTrayIcon()
        {
            var notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
            notifyIcon.Visible = true;

            return notifyIcon;
        }

        public static void UpdateIcon(NotifyIcon notifyIcon, string text)
        {
            using (var b = new Bitmap(16, 16))
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
            using (var font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericMonospace, 8))
            {
                g.DrawString(text, font, Brushes.Black, 0, 0);

                var icon = b.GetHicon();
                try
                {
                    notifyIcon.Icon = Icon.FromHandle(icon);
                } finally
                {
                    DestroyIcon(icon);
                }
            }
        }
    }
"@

$icon = [TextNotifyIcon]::CreateTrayIcon()
while ($true) {
   $text = Get-NotifyIconText
   [TextNotifyIcon]::UpdateIcon($icon, $text)
   [Threading.Thread]::Sleep(1000)
}
```

Comment: The icon doesn't go away upon exit.